# pi4j button listener with servlet or java web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, listener, raspberry-pi

I am using pi4j for control raspberry pi, so the example is like that,

final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

```
    // create and register gpio pin listener
    myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
            // display pin state on console
            System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
        }

    });
```

it is working for java se app but i want to use in java webapp this listener, 
how can i implement this button listener, actually is it possible ?

thanks,

Comment: this listener is used in the main method, I think there is no main in the java ee ?

Comment: What should your webapp do?